# How to create 2 tables with relationships to each other through shell?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, psql

```
const Branch  = sequelize.define('branch', {
    id:                  {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    name:                {type: DataTypes.STRING,  allowNull: false },
})

const BranchCredit  = sequelize.define('branch_credit', {
    id:                  {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    name:                {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
})

const BranchCreditPayment  = sequelize.define('branch_credit_payment', {
    id:                  {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    name:                {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
})

Branch.hasMany(BranchCredit, {as: 'branch_credit'})
BranchCredit.belongsTo(Branch)

BranchCredit.hasMany(BranchCreditPayment, {as: 'branch_credit_payments'})
BranchCreditPayment.belongsTo(BranchCredit)`
```

In localhost i've extended the database by these code (sequiluze, nodejs), then simply drop and created the new, but production has already has a database, and I need to extend it, this code create tables/realationships but not able to extend, so I need to do it by psql shell, so How can I do it right ?

I've tried to execute this pipeline:

`create table branch_credit (id serial PRIMARY KEY, "branchId" integer not null, sum varchar(250) not null, date varchar(250) not null);`

`create table branch_credit_payments (id serial PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(250) not null, "branchCreditId" integer references branch_credit (id), unique("branchCreditId"));`

but it throws me error

Comment: can you provide the error that you're receiving?

Comment: @mikrowdev routine: "parserOpenTable"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're creating properly the SQL relation, can you try instead of

```sql
create table branch_credit(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    "branchId" integer not null,
    sum varchar(250) not null,
    date varchar(250) not null
);

create table branch_credit_payments (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(250) not null,
    "branchCreditId" integer references branch_credit (id),
    unique("branchCreditId")
);
```

To explicit define the foreign key like this

```sql
create table branch_credit(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    "branchId" integer not null,
    sum varchar(250) not null,
    date varchar(250) not null
);

create table branch_credit_payments (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(250) not null,
    "branchCreditId" integer,
    
    foreign key("branchCreditId") references branch_credit(id),
    
    unique("branchCreditId")
);
```